# JavaFX: cannot load .css or .ttf from another library's resources

Tags: css, javafx, jar

My project is structured as follows:

**Program1.jar**

```
Main.java
```

**Program1Library.jar**

```
...
resources
-font
--blah1.ttf
--blah2.ttf
-css
--dark1.css
--dark2.css
```

I have separated various stuff into a library as they are being reused in other projects, now I want to separate as well the CSS and Fonts. The issue is that it does not load the CSS or the Font, the path seems to be correct but something is wrong.

Question 1: is is possible to load a CSS/TTF file from another .JAR? and use it in the current .JAR?

Question 2: if so, can I have your example, mine does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I only can guess how the rest of your project structure looks like and how you are referencing the resources. So try to place a dummy class into your library sources folder:

```
src
-css (package-name)
--Dummy.java
resources
-font
--blah1.ttf
--blah2.ttf
-css
--dark1.css
--dark2.css
```

Then:

```
Dummy.class.getResource("dark1.css");
```

or:

```
Dummy.class.getResource("/css/dark1.css");
```

Assuming that the library jar is in the classpath

Comment: I can gather anything from within the main .JAR, what I cannot get are files from another .JAR (which in my case is a library). How can I get files from an external .JAR?

Comment: Use the code above in your main jar. That way you can access the resources in the external jar. The external jar has to be in the classpath of your "main jar" while executed. The getResource-method then returns a URL to the external jar in addition the path of the internal structure leading to the resources. Adding the Dummy-class to the external jar just makes it easier for you to address the external jar from your main jar.

Comment: I can see where you are pointing, yet this does not solve my issue. I managed to get from one JAR to another JAR but in a very messy way, and I hope for a better approach.